# please check this code. as I am trying to add the repository with @BindValue. the hilt is throwing error as follows

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, bindvalue

#### please check this code. as I am trying to add the repository with @BindValue. the hilt is throwing error as follows.

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidTest
@UninstallModules(AppModule::class)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class RandomUserListFragmentTest {
    @get:Rule
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

 @Inject
    lateinit var glideRequestManager: RequestManager

    @BindValue
    @JvmField  val repository:RandomUserRepository= RandomUserRepositoryImplTest()

  @Before
    fun launchFragment() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        ActivityScenario.launch(RandomUserActivity::class.java)
    }


   @Test
    fun verifyTheRecyclerViewHasData(){
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recyclerView)).check { view, noViewFoundException ->
            if (noViewFoundException != null) {
                throw noViewFoundException
            }

            val recyclerView = view as RecyclerView
            Assert.assertEquals(3, recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount)
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [AppModule::class]
)
object FakeAppModuleTest {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun initGlide(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): RequestManager = Glide.with(appContext)
        .setDefaultRequestOptions(
            RequestOptions()
                .centerInside()
                .error(R.drawable.ic_user)
        )
}
```

#### getting errors like

> Task :app:hiltJavaCompileDebugAndroidTest
> /Users/shaheer/AndroidStudioProjects/ssassignment/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/debugAndroidTest/com/ss/assignment/ui/random_user_ui/RandomUserActivityTest_TestComponentDataSupplier.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
> import dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.root.DaggerRandomUserActivityTest_HiltComponents_SingletonC;
> ^
> symbol:   class DaggerRandomUserActivityTest_HiltComponents_SingletonC
> location: package dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.root
> /Users/shaheer/AndroidStudioProjects/ssassignment/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/debugAndroidTest/com/ss/assignment/ui/random_user_ui/main_screen/RandomUserListFragmentTest_TestComponentDataSupplier.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
> import dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.root.DaggerRandomUserListFragmentTest_HiltComponents_SingletonC;
> ^
> symbol:   class DaggerRandomUserListFragmentTest_HiltComponents_SingletonC
> location: package dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.root
> /Users/shaheer/AndroidStudioProjects/ssassignment/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/debugAndroidTest/dagger/hilt/android/internal/testing/root/RandomUserActivityTest_HiltComponents.java:133: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.ss.assignment.data.repository.RandomUserRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
> public abstract static class SingletonC implements SunAndSandsApp_GeneratedInjector,
> ^
> com.ss.assignment.data.repository.RandomUserRepository is injected at
> com.ss.assignment.ui.random_user_ui.RandomUserSharedViewModel(randomUserRepository)
> com.ss.assignment.ui.random_user_ui.RandomUserSharedViewModel is injected at
> com.ss.assignment.ui.random_user_ui.RandomUserSharedViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
> @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
> dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.root.RandomUserActivityTest_HiltComponents.SingletonC → dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.root.RandomUserActivityTest_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.root.RandomUserActivityTest_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
> 3 errors

please correct me if I am doing some mistakes here...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but the issue was actually a missing `@Provides` method in my `AppModuleTest`. I had added a new method to my `AppModule` class but forgot to include it in my test module. Even though the new value wasn't being used by any of my tests, adding it to the test module solved the problem and allowed my tests to run.